# how to get result from a variable passed as a parameter calling a function in external dll using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I need to call a function in an external dll.
I declare dll and function like this:

```vb
<DllImport("somedll.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Shared Function somefunction(ByVal XMLResponse As String, ByVal XMLSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

Documentation indicates `somefunction` function uses the `XMLResponse` parameter as a buffer in order to store the response with some data. And `XMLSize` is the size of this buffer.

My question is how to get the response and how to declare this buffer in order to get the response after call the function.

I know how to pass a value to a function, but I never seen this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `but I never seen this situation` - it is, however, *the* most common situation when calling native functions.

Comment: you can believe me. i have more than 30 years programming.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
<DllImport("somedll.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Shared Function somefunction(ByVal XMLResponse As StringBuilder, ByVal XMLSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

```vb
dim sb = new StringBuilder(100)

somefunction(sb, sb.Capacity)
```

You will need to verify what charset the function expects, and add it to the DllImport attribute.